# How to put a dateset containes two different types of data into two different list in python using for loop only?

Tags: python

data for example

10/11/2015,129.177551

how do I build two lists?
Date [] and price [] should contain date and price separately

Comment: what format is your data in? Do you have `data = "10/11/2015,129.177551"`?

Comment: yes also other many similar lines like that

Comment: Why should `Data` and `price` be lists? Should it not be `Date = "10/11/2015"` and `price = "129.177551"`?

Comment: What exactly should `Date` and `price` be after running your code?

Comment: because the data set contains many different dates and prices. and the question was to use a for loop to access each element of the data,
process each string and element by element build the dates and prices lists.

Comment: should be two different lists Date [10/11/2022, 11/20/2021 etc..] and Prices[132.98, 140.89 etc..]

Comment: So you have a variable `data_list = ["10/11/2015,129.177551", similar strings]`? If so, what is that variables name?

Comment: all as one string called data?

Comment: it's a CSV file and contains data like this 10/11/2015,129.177551
11/11/2015,129.035141
12/11/2015,126.854782
13/11/2015,126.899254
16/11/2015,128.527878
17/11/2015,130.005234
18/11/2015,131.96312
19/11/2015,132.81752
20/11/2015,132.959869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you data is in csv, you can use `pandas` package:

file.csv

```
10/11/2015,129.177551
10/11/2015,129.177551
```

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', header=False)
date = df.iloc[0,:].tolist()
price = df.iloc[1,:].tolist()
```

Though most people just leave the data in the pandas DataFrame for further processing.

---

If you data is in a string

```
data = '''10/11/2015,129.177551
10/11/2015,129.177551'''

data = [line.split(',') for line in data.split('\n')]
date, price = zip(*data)
```

---

And if you want to use for loop:

```
data = '''10/11/2015,129.177551
10/11/2015,129.177551'''

date = []
price = []
for line in data.split('\n'):
    d, p = line.split(',')
    date.append(d)
    price.append(p)
```

As you can see, method 1 (list comprehension) is much shorter.